# If $f$ is an entire function such that $|f(z)| \le 2 \ln (|z|+1)$ for all $z \in \Bbb{C}$, then $f(z) = 0$ for all $z \in \Bbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, entire-functions

> Suppose $f$ is an entire function such that $|f(z)| \le 2 \ln (|z|+1)$ for all $z \in \Bbb{C}$. Prove that $f(z) = 0$ for all $z \in \Bbb{C}$.

Here is my solution which I am hoping someone could check:

> First, it easily follows from the hypothesis that $f(0)= 0$, so if we could prove $f$ is constant, then it would automatically follow that $f=0$ on $\Bbb{C}$. Indeed,
>
> $$|f(0)| \le 2 \ln (|0|+1) = 2 \ln (1) = 0.$$
> Now, let us prove that $f$ is constant. Let $z_0 \in \Bbb{C}$ and $r > 0$ arbitrary. Then, because $f$ is entire, we know it is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $\overline{B(z_0,r)}$, so Cauchy estimates tell us that
>
> $$|f'(z_0)| \le \frac{\sup_{|z-z_0|=r} |f(z)|}{r} \le 2 \frac{\sup_{|z-z_0|=r} \ln (|z|+1)}{r}.$$
> Let $z$ be any complex number satisfying $|z-z_0| = r$. Then there exists a unit complex number $w_z$ such that $z = rw_z + z_0$. Since $x \mapsto \ln x$ is an increasing function on $(0,\infty)$, we have
>
> $$\ln(|z| + 1) = \ln(|rw_z + z_0| + 1) \le \ln (|rw_{z}| + |z_0| + 1) = \ln (r + z_0 + 1)$$
> and hence,
>
> $$|f'(z_0)| \le 2 \frac{\ln (r + z_0 + 1)}{r}.$$
> As $r \to \infty$, the numerator and denominator of the fraction on the RHS go to $\infty$. But L'Hôpital's rule says
>
> $$|f'(z_0)| \le 2 \lim_{r \to \infty} \frac{\ln (r + z_0 + 1)}{r} = 2 \lim_{r \to \infty} \frac{1}{r + |z_0| + 1} = 0,$$
> so $f'(z_0)=0$. Since $z_0$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f'=0$ and therefore $f$ is constant. But, by our initial remark, we know this means $f=0$ on $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Nicely done!

Comment: @jasnee Thank you!

Comment: Nice proof! Clear and super easy to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your solution looks nice. I just want to add a similar solution using a Taylor series.

Since $f$ is entire,
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$$
on $\mathbb{C}$ and $$a_n = \frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_R}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz,$$
where $C_R$ is circle of radius $R>0$ centered at $0$.

Note that on $C_R$,
$$\left|\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\right| \leq \frac{2 \ln (R+1)}{R^{n+1}}.$$
Thus,
$$|a_n|= \left| \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_R} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz\right| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{2 \ln (R+1)}{R^{n+1}} \cdot 2 \pi R = \frac{2 \ln (R+1)}{R^n} \to 0$$
as $R \to \infty$ for all $n \geq 1$. This implies that $a_n=0$ for all $n\geq 1$. Thus, $f(z) \equiv a_0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

As you said, $f(0) = 0$, so $f(z) \equiv 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.